# Cytoscape JS - Redraw Nodes after Font Change

Tags: cytoscape.js

My Cytoscape Diagram has a style of

```js
selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': '#efefef',
        'label': function(ele) { return ele.data('name'); },
        'font-family' : 'Calibri',
        'font-size' : '10px',
        'shape' : 'ellipse',
        'text-halign' : 'center' ,
        'text-valign' : 'center',
        'width' : 'label' ,
        'padding' : '8px' ,
  'text-wrap' : 'wrap' ,
  'text-max-width' : '120px' ,
  'border-color' : '#ffbb33',
  'border-style' : 'solid' ,
  'border-width' : '1'
      }
```

I have a dropdown box allowing users to select a font. When the user changes the font in the drop down, I essentially run this peice of code

```js
$('#font').change(function(){
    
    window.cy.nodes().forEach(function( ele ){
     ele.style('font-family', $('#font').val());
    });
    
    window.cy.resize();
    //window.cy.layout({name : 'klay'}).run();
    //window.cy.elements('#13, #14, #15, #16, #17, #18').layout({name: 'cose'}).run();
   });
```

The nodes get updated with the new font, but the text does not remain within the drawn ellipse as the font has changed.

How do I get the nodes to re-render after applying a style change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It is very simple - Change the Style and update using window.cy.json({});

```
$('.x-bold').click(function(){
    let cyJson = window.cy.json(true);
    let style = cyJson.style[0];

    style.style['font-weight'] = 'bold';
    cyJson.style[0] = style;

    window.cy.json({style : cyJson.style });

});
```